# Simple css transition doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, transition

I have some problem with repeating animation in Firefox and Chrome. 
I use simple js to make it repeatable.

```
(function step() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var coin7 = document.getElementById('coin7');
        coin7.style.display = 'block';
        coin7.style.height = "210px";
    }, 2000)

    setTimeout(function(){
        coin7.style.display = "none";
        coin7.style.height = "0";
    },6000);
    setTimeout(step, 7000)
})();
```

Demolink http://jsfiddle.net/pe461zrn/

First iteration is ok in all browsers, but second and next doesn't apply css transition in FF39 and latest Chrome. And it's still work fine at all iteration in IE11.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try applying height with timeout 0 so you are sure it happens after display is set to block (which is something that would prevent animation)

```
setTimeout(function(){coin7.style.height = "210px";}, 0);
```

Comment: This solution works brilliant, but with 10ms or more at second argument of setTimeout. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Just remove `coin7.style.display = 'none';` and thats the solution

HTML

```
<div id="coin7" style=""> 
  <img src="http://us.cdn4.123rf.com/168nwm/kristijanzontar/kristijanzontar1101/kristijanzontar110100013/8612198-.jpg" /> 
  </div>
```

CSS

```
#coin7 {
      overflow: hidden; display: block; height: 0px;
        -moz-transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
        }
```

Javascript

```
(function step() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var coin7 = document.getElementById('coin7');
        coin7.style.display = 'block';
        coin7.style.height = "210px";
    }, 2000)

    setTimeout(function(){
        coin7.style.height = "0px";
    },6000);
    setTimeout(step, 7000)
})();
```

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xt85qepu/)

Comment: Yap, it works, and I need to save logic of displaing that's why I can't use your solution. Thank you for helping.